# Wrapping primitives in a simple class

Tags: c++

I made this `Primitive` class recently for my OpenGL engine. It basically wraps all basic primitive shapes, like cones, toruses, and cubes, which the user can use for various things. I would like to ask your advice on improving my class design in any ways.

**Primitives.h:**

```
#pragma once

#include "alpha/Mesh.h"
#include "alpha/Transform.h"
#include <glm/glm.hpp>

class Primitive
{
public:
    Primitive   (
                        glm::vec3 pos = glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                        glm::vec3 rot = glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                        glm::vec3 scale = glm::vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
                )
        :
            m_transform(pos, rot, scale)
        {}

    virtual ~Primitive() = 0;

    void Render(){ m_mesh->Draw(); }

    void SetPosition(glm::vec3 pos){m_transform.SetPos(pos);}
    void SetRotation(glm::vec3 rot){ m_transform.SetRot(rot);}
    void SetScale(glm::vec3 scale){m_transform.SetScale(scale);}

    glm::vec3 GetPosition(){ return m_transform.GetPos(); }
    glm::vec3 GetRotation(){ return m_transform.GetRot(); }
    glm::vec3 GetScale(){ return m_transform.GetScale(); }

    void OffSetPosition(glm::vec3 position) { m_transform.GetPos() += position; }
    void OffSetRotation(glm::vec3 rotation) { m_transform.GetPos() += rotation; }
    void OffSetScale(glm::vec3 scale) { m_transform.GetPos() += scale; }

    Transform GetTransform() const{ return m_transform; }
    void SetTransform(Transform transform){ m_transform = transform; }
protected:
    Mesh m_mesh;
    Transform m_transform;
};

class PrimitiveCube : public Primitive{
public:
    PrimitiveCube   (
                        glm::vec3 pos = glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                        glm::vec3 rot = glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                        glm::vec3 scale = glm::vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
                    )
        :
            Primitive::Primitive(pos, rot, scale)
    {
        Primitive::m_mesh = CreateMesh("res/models/primitives/Cube.obj");
    }
};

class PrimitivePlane : public Primitive{
public:
    PrimitivePlane  (
                        glm::vec3 pos = glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                        glm::vec3 rot = glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                        glm::vec3 scale = glm::vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
                    )
        :
            Primitive::Primitive(pos, rot, scale)
    {
        Primitive::m_mesh = CreateMesh("res/models/primitives/Plane.obj");
    }
};

class PrimitiveUVSphere : public Primitive{
public:
    PrimitiveUVSphere   (
                        glm::vec3 pos = glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                        glm::vec3 rot = glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                        glm::vec3 scale = glm::vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
                    )
        :
            Primitive::Primitive(pos, rot, scale)
    {
        Primitive::m_mesh = CreateMesh("res/models/primitives/UVSphere.obj");
    }
};

class PrimitiveICOSphere : public Primitive{
public:
    PrimitiveICOSphere  (
                        glm::vec3 pos = glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                        glm::vec3 rot = glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                        glm::vec3 scale = glm::vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
                    )
        :
            Primitive::Primitive(pos, rot, scale)
    {
        Primitive::m_mesh = CreateMesh("res/models/primitives/ICOSphere.obj");
    }
};

class PrimitiveCylinder : public Primitive{
public:
    PrimitiveCylinder   (
                        glm::vec3 pos = glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                        glm::vec3 rot = glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                        glm::vec3 scale = glm::vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
                    )
        :
            Primitive::Primitive(pos, rot, scale)
    {
        Primitive::m_mesh = CreateMesh("res/models/primitives/Cylinder.obj");
    }
};

class PrimitiveTorus : public Primitive{
public:
    PrimitiveTorus  (
                        glm::vec3 pos = glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                        glm::vec3 rot = glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                        glm::vec3 scale = glm::vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
                    )
        :
            Primitive::Primitive(pos, rot, scale)
    {
        Primitive::m_mesh = CreateMesh("res/models/primitives/Torus.obj");
    }
};

class PrimitiveCone : public Primitive{
public:
    PrimitiveCone   (
                        glm::vec3 pos = glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                        glm::vec3 rot = glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                        glm::vec3 scale = glm::vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
                    )
        :
            Primitive::Primitive(pos, rot, scale)
    {
        Primitive::m_mesh = CreateMesh("res/models/primitives/Cone.obj");
    }
};
```

**Primitives.cpp:**

```
#include "alpha/Primitives.h"

Primitive::~Primitive(){}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the point of having default values for constructor when you overwrite them in every derived class with the same set of values. It just adds a lot of lines for no good reason. Ideally, you would default these in transform, as you are asking for neutral transformation matrix, so you don't have to write out these vectors every time you want this matrix.

---

I don't see any good reason why would you even want to have separate class for every primitive. You should either put paths in enum choice in main class and decide in constructor what primitive you want to create - since only difference between these is path to the mesh - or, better in my opinion, but also more costly, create generator for each primitive. This will not only remove unnecessary IO and .obj parsing, but you will gain a lot of flexibility as well.

Unit cube is no-brainer, but with torus for example, you want to specify inner and outer radius, possibly step in degrees for regulating number of triangles.

---

Adding method for setting transformation parameters that returns this will allow you to set them in one line with construction fluent like style, and it will remove from constructor options that are not as frequent (assumption).

---

Your method Render calls method Draw. This seems like a bit of inconsistency. Decide on what you gonna use and stick with it. This way, if I see a lot of render and then draw pops out, I will suspect it to behave differently, even though that is not the case (assumption).

---

Similarly your methods in transformation do have GetPos, but primitive has GetPosition. I would personally prefer the latter. Up to you, just stay consistent.

---

Add return value to your setters (this) so you can use the class more fluently.

---

Consider returning new instances for your vectors and transformation (unless it is design intention), for you can cause quite a few bugs to yourself by modifying a value while affecting some object unrelated to the spot you just modified.

---

Consider specifying that you are using glm namespace, so you don't have to write it out all the time. (did not check for collisions)

---

Hope this helps, regards.

Comment: Should I provide mesh type as a template argument ?

Comment: You pass primitive type as an argument to constructor of Primitive class.

Comment: Ok, so I can pass an enum member like **Primitive cube = Primitive(PRIMITIVE_CUBE);**

Comment: But wouldn't templates be faster ? (Types distinguished at compile time...)

Comment: Unless you are creating millions of these, it's in my opinion unnecessary obfuscation. And remember, measure before making any optimization decisions. Usually, it is waste of time.

Comment: The thing is that might be some thousands out there if I'm creating a tiled map :) But I think I''l stick with your advice.

Answer (score 3):

**Class hierarchy**

As stated by Vojtěch Kaiser, it is a bit silly to have this entire class hierarchy when the only differences are paths. The idea is that your inherited classes only define the behavior that is different from the base class.

**Useless code**

The following code may not do what you intended, if `Transform::GetPos()` is implemented the same as `Primitive::GetPosition()`

```
void OffSetPosition(glm::vec3 position) { m_transform.GetPos() += position; }
```

This is because `GetPosition()` returns a *copy* of, not a *reference*. So you change the copy, not the reference. Either make sure it returns a reference or change your code to something like this:

```
void OffSetPosition(glm::vec3 position) { m_transform.SetPos(m_transform.GetPos() += position); }
```

**Deleted functions**

Does this compile? Since you deleted the destructor of Primitive (`virtual ~Primitive() = 0;`), but in your cpp you do define it!

**Const correctness**

Try to mark functions and arguments that do not (or should not) change as const. For example, all getter functions should not modify your object so they can all be marked as const:

```
glm::vec3 GetPosition() const { return m_transform.GetPos(); }
glm::vec3 GetRotation() const { return m_transform.GetRot(); }
glm::vec3 GetScale() const { return m_transform.GetScale(); }

void SetPosition(const glm::vec3 pos){ m_transform.SetPos(pos); }
void SetRotation(const glm::vec3 rot){ m_transform.SetRot(rot); }
void SetScale(const glm::vec3 scale){ m_transform.SetScale(scale); }
```

This helps the compiler catching logical errors in your code and helps other users understand your code faster.

---

Regarding performance:

**Const references & move operators**

If you pass a parameter by value it is copied over. So that means that every time someone calls `Transform GetTransform() const { return m_transform; }`, a copy of a Transform object is created. The same for parameters in setters and constructors. To prevent useless copying, use [const references or move operators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/270408/3510322) where possible.

Comment: Yes, it does compile; look at this post -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640985/making-a-class-abstract-without-any-pure-virtual-methods : it is totally legal  in ISO C++